# C# Как при наведении на элемент из СПИСКА сделать эффект фокуса именно на ВЫДЕЛЕННЫЙ элемент из списка?

Tags: c#, коллекции

Вот код:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroForm
    {
        int sm = 20; //координата Top'а picturebox'а, которая будет постоянно увеличиваться
        private Point mousePos; //Координата мыши
        List<PictureBox> pb; //Это будет контейнер для PictureBox'ов
        PictureBox activePB; //Активный PictureBox, который перемещаем
        int coun = 0; 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pb = new List<PictureBox>(); //Создадим списочек при инициализации формы
        pb.Add(pictureBox2); //добавим самый первый picturebox в список
    }

    public abstract class AbstractGraphic
    {
        public int width, height, x, y;

        public void Draw()
        {
        }
    }

    class Port : AbstractGraphic
    {
        string connectTo;

        public Port(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            base.x = x;
            base.y = y;
            base.width = width;
            base.height = height;
        }

        void Colizion(Port x, Port y)
        {
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
        }

    }

    class Panel : AbstractGraphic
    {
        static int countPort;
        Port[] ports = new Port[countPort];

        public Panel(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            base.x = x;
            base.y = y;
            base.width = width;
            base.height = height;
        }

        void Add(Port[] ports)
        {
        }

        void Colizion(Panel x, Panel y)
        {
        }

        void Delete()
        {
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
        }

    }

    class ServerRack : AbstractGraphic
    {
        string file;
        static int panelCount;
        Panel[] panels = new Panel[panelCount];

        public ServerRack(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            base.x = x;
            base.y = y;
            base.width = width;
            base.height = height;
        }

        void Add(Port[] ports, int unit)
        {
        }

        void Colizion(Panel x, Panel y)
        {
        }

        void Delete(int unit)
        {
        }

        void Draw()
        {
        }

        void Load(string file)
        {
            this.file = file;
        }

        void Save()
        {
        }
    }

    class Client
    {
        ServerRack serverRack;

        void ConfigFile()
        {
        }

        void Main()
        {
        }

        void SearchFile()
        {
        }
    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        pictureboxCreate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mousePos = e.Location;
            foreach (PictureBox picture in pb)
            {
                if (picture.Capture == true)
                {
                    activePB = picture;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            activePB.Left = e.X + activePB.Left - mousePos.X;
            activePB.Top = e.Y + activePB.Top - mousePos.Y;
        }
    }

    private void pictureboxCreate()
    {
        //Если была выбрана и загружена картинка, то...
        Image img = pictureBox2.Image;
        //...создадим новый PictureBox, загрузим в него картинку и укажем
        //дополнительные параметры для него.
        var picbox = new PictureBox();
        picbox.Image = img;
        picbox.Left = pictureBox2.Left;
        picbox.Width = pictureBox2.Width;
        picbox.Height = pictureBox2.Height;
        picbox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            picbox.Top = pictureBox2.Top - sm;
            sm = sm + 20;
        }
        //Назначим обработчик события MouseDown
        picbox.MouseDown += pictureBox1_MouseDown;
        picbox.MouseMove += pictureBox1_MouseMove;
        picbox.MouseEnter += pictureBox1_MouseEnter;
        picbox.MouseLeave += pictureBox1_MouseLeave;
        //Добавим созданный PictureBox в списочек
        pb.Add(picbox);
        //И сделаем его активным
        activePB = picbox;
        panel2.Controls.Add(picbox);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (PictureBox picture in pb)
        {
            if (picture.Capture == true)
            {
                activePB = picture;
                activePB.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            }
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        activePB.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
    }

}
```

Обращать внимания нужно на события MouseEnter, MouseLeave, ибо там я полагаю должна происходить коллизия. Только вопрос, как при наведении на один элемент, из целого списка, выделить только тот элемент, который был наведёт курсором мыши?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы обратиться к контролу, который вызвал событие, используйте `sender`. Контрол, вызывающий событие всегда передает себя в этот аргумент.

```csharp
private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox picture = sender as PictureBox;
    // picture - тот самый контрол, куда только что навелась мышь
}
```